# Converting barcode text to code128 required format for Microsoft Word to render as font

Tags: javascript, fonts, ms-word, barcode, dynamics-crm-2016

I am trying to convert an alphanumeric text to the required format of Code128 barcode type. I will then embed this in Microsoft Word template which has code128 type fonts installed and print it out to make it scannable.

Code39 works as intended because it is easy to convert it into the required format. You just start and end with asterisk (*).

How can I convert a text to required string for code128 format in javascript?

I have tried the open source JsBarcode library. I can get the binary data of the barcode, can I convert from there, or should I just look up the code128 table and make the ascii calculations?

Example Input:

```
Code 128456
```

Example Output:

```
ÌCodeÂÇ,tXXÎ
```

[Reference](https://www.idautomation.com/kb/scan-font.html)

Thanks.

Comment: Can I ask why you aren't using this: https://www.idautomation.com/font-encoders/vba-macro/ ?

Answer (score 0):

A Code 128 "font" is a pseudo-font, the input is not text characters, it's calculated space and mark "characters". The computed "characters" depend on the designer of the font. So you'll have to identify it and use the designer's algorithm.

Code 128 also has the added complexity of a checksum. That has to be computed and rendered with space and mark "characters," too.

So, you'll always need to render the output of function and apply the font to it. Applying a Code 128 font to text won't work.