# Code128 in Report in MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, barcode, code128

I looked for a solution around the Internet to be able to show Code128 in a report in MS Access. However, downloading a font that just shows the characters in code-128 was not working. My scanner would just not scan the barcode.

Since all other solutions I found were quite costly I thought that I might just write my own conversion code, but I need a starting point. I don't really know what the costly solutions make differently than just printing lines like the Code 128 font I downloaded.

I find it difficult to imagine how to specify the needs of such a conversion algorithm so I am looking for someone with experience who could guide me a bit there.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50175029/converting-barcode-text-to-code128-required-format-for-microsoft-word-to-render - you can't just render the text using the barcode font: you need some VBA to "translate" and then apply the font to the output

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generating Code 128 Barcodes using Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13909248/generating-code-128-barcodes-using-excel-vba)

Comment: The host being Access is not significant here. The solution would be the same for any VBA host application.

Comment: Use the font from here:  http://grandzebu.net/informatique/codbar-en/code128.htm  The font has to "pair" with the code.  I saw the same issue until I replaced the font.

Comment: @HackSlash I already tried using your suggestion but the function generated weird fragments for me. Was solved it seems. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63137735/code-128-barcode-in-vba-for-access-not-working-properly/63140344#63140344 OP should be edited accordingly

Answer (score 0):

For most barcode fonts, you probably are not creating check digits.  They can still decode, but you usually need to wrap the "field" in special characters.  Most use "*" or "!".  So, instead of just displaying 8675309 you would need to display *8675309(cant display the second * on stack overflow) or !8675309! - do this and then your bardcode reader should decode with the font.